# GCP Dataproc - Error: Unknown name "optionalComponents" at 'cluster.config': Cannot find field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to create dataproc cluster using configurations mentioned in YAML file (using [import](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataproc/clusters/import)):

The command I have been using successfully:

```
$ gcloud beta dataproc clusters import $CLUSTER_NAME --region=$REGION 
--source=cluster_conf_file.yaml
```

Later on I tried adding HABSE component which is a part of [available optional components](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/overview) using attribute `--optional-components`:

```
$ gcloud beta dataproc clusters import $CLUSTER_NAME --optional-components=HBASE --region=$REGION 
--source=cluster_conf_file.yaml
```

(Documentation referred:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/hbase#installing_the_component)

Which caused below error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.import) unrecognized arguments: --optional-components=HBASE
```

Then I tried adding the attribute `--optional-components` as `optionalComponents` in the YAML file (instead of passing through command line) by referring [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/ClusterConfig#softwareconfig) documentation.

Sample YAML:

```
config:
  endpointConfig:
    enableHttpPortAccess: BOOLEAN_VALUE
  configBucket: BUCKET_NAME
  gceClusterConfig:
    serviceAccount: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
    subnetworkUri: SUBNETWORK_URI
    tags:
      - Tag1
      - TAG2
  optionalComponents:            <---- Attribute causing error
    - HBASE
  softwareConfig:
    imageVersion: IMAGE_VERSION
    properties:
      PROPERTY: VALUE
      .
      .
      .
  masterConfig:
    diskConfig:
      bootDiskSizeGb: SIZE
      bootDiskType: TYPE
    machineTypeUri: TYPE_URI
    numInstances: COUNT
```

Which caused below error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.import) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "optionalComponents" at 'cluster.config': Cannot find field.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"optionalComponents\"\
      \ at 'cluster.config': Cannot find field."
    field: cluster.config
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optionalComponents` should be under `config.softwareConfig`:

```
config:
  ...
  softwareConfig:
    imageVersion: IMAGE_VERSION
    optionalComponents:
    - ZOOKEEPER
    - HBASE
```

You can prove it by first creating a cluster with optional components, then export it to a YAML file.